# Adding a checkbox column to tables with values dynamically generated from a database in php

Tags: php, html

I want to add a column in my table that will contain check boxes that if it will be selected I may be able to get all the id's of the selected row data.

Here's my code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM Client";
                $qry = mysql_query($sql);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>$row[name]</td>
                            <td>$row[company]</td>
                            <td>$row[address]</td>
                        </tr>";
                }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is, how could I add another column that will contain check boxes that will represent the id of row data being selected. And how can I retrieve those values? Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to do with the values? its quite easy to work with (id - primary key field) such as you did with (name, company, and address) just add <td>$row[id]</td> please replace id with id in your table. After this, you can replace it with ( <input name="id" type="checkbox" value=""> ) please this is just a pattern not exact answer.

Comment: I wanted to get those id's selected to be able to perform a delete function that will delete all those selected values.

Comment: can you post your table columns?

Comment: ClientId,Name,Company,Address these are my columns in the database.

Comment: add this to while loop. <input name="ClientId[$row[ClientId]]" type="checkbox" value="$row[ClientId]"> after this, you need a form for sending selected chekcboxes, or you can depend on javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an another  and create a check box array and store the value.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
   echo "<tr>
            <td>$row[name]</td>
            <td>$row[company]</td>
            <td>$row[address]</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='row_id[]' id='rowid_<?php echo $id ?>' value='<?php echo $id ?>' />
         </tr>";
}
```

Then you can retrieve the values by using $_POST[] method and use whatever you want.

```
$rowid      = $_POST['row_id'];
```

But it will return the selected checkboxes value in an array format. You can use a loop to access all the elements or you can use `implode()` function to use as a string.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be trying that one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database table layout. In the best case you have an auto increment column called company_id. Otherwise it will be very hard to distinguish between rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
                echo "<tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' id='$row[id]' name='$row[id]'></td>
                        <td>$row[name]</td>
                        <td>$row[company]</td>
                        <td>$row[address]</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
```

Comment: There is a condition fro my answer is it need an id field in that table and it may auto increment or an manual entry