# Insert checkboxes into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Would like some help on how to store values from dynamic checkboxes into a mySQL table using php.

```
                    ID |        DES_ID  | CAT_ID
                    1           0921671     12
                    2           0921671     24
                    3           0921671     30
```

I generate my checkboxes like this.

```
<?php 
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_category order by name ");
                $i=1;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value='.$row['category_id'].' id='.$row['name'].'>'.'<label for='.$row['name'].' class="fil_lab">'.$row['name']. '</label>';
                if($i%5==0)
                {
                 $i = 0;
                 echo '<br><br>';
                }
                $i++;}
            ?>
```

Note: I will add those checkboxes as other data like, Destination Name etc. . I have a total of 4 tables to be inserted at the same time.

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555878/adding-a-checkbox-column-to-tables-with-values-dynamically-generated-from-a-data#comment20307418_14555878

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate table for check boxes, which you can link with a foreign key to main table.

OR

You can create a field in main table and store check box values like this (0|1|2) but this is not a good method, follow the first one.

Comment: I'm doing what you said first. But I don't know how to make a for loop insert for it would you help please.

Comment: You will get all the check boxes in an array, loop the array add insert query inside the loop.

Comment: But what if i have other values? will the other values also be repeated? like name,address?

Comment: no it will not repeat, Post your code here I can explain based on that.